# Updating Multiple Child Entities from a Parent Edit Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 C# project using Entity Framework and I want to know how I can update multiple child entities from a parent entity.

I am using a view model to send the data from the two models to the view:

```
public class ResultData
    {
        public Result Result { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ResultNote> ResultNotes { get; set; }
    }
```

So I'm wanting to update all of Result's notes on the Result Edit form.

My View:

```
@model RSC3_DB.ViewModels.ResultData
@foreach (var note in Model.ResultNotes)
  {
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => note.NoteText)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => note.NoteText)
    </div>
  }
```

This renders them on the form correctly. My question is what do I need to put in the Result controller "[HttpPost]ActionResult Edit" method to make the changes to the ResultNotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just have to use a for loop with assigned an assigned index value and list each model attribute out.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.ResultNotes.Count(); i++ )
```